# Search from more than one column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, search-results

I am new to SharePoint and I am trying to make a search bar to a Data View Web Part. I realised that the search bar can only filter one parameter at a time. Is there anyway that I can customize my search bar to filter more than parameter from more than one column.

Eg.My table Users consists of 5 columns: Name,UserID,Date,Sales,Quantity.
I would like my search bar to filter UserID and Name. In other words, I want my search bar to pass either parameter to the Data View Web part.

Any advice for this newbie? Thanks!

Comment: You can search for multiple columns if you are using managed properties. What version of SP are you using?